# Tensorflow export and reuse Estimator object in Python

Tags: tensorflow, compilation, export

The question is about Tensorflow and its higher API Estimator and more generally about exporting and reusing models.

There exists several facilities to export a tensorflow models: tf.train.Saver, write and importing graph directly with their associated weights.

My interests lies in the tf.estimator.Estimator object and how we could reuse them. My use case is pretty simple: I fit a simple model say in tensorflow and would like to use its predictions in a more involved one.

There exists a `export_savemodel` method for serving the model, however I would need to make communication in my model through ports and I am not sure if this is optimal for training.

My question are the following:

1. Is there a (simple) way to use and import the output of `export_savemodel` in python? I guessed you could technically use the C++ code and create wrapper around them?
2. Is there an efficient way to compile an `tf.estimator.Estimator` and reuse it in Python? The XLA compiler seems be interesting, but I could not find out if I could use the result back in Python.
3. Generally, what are the best practice on how to reuse previously trained models in Tensorflow?

Thanks a lot for your reading!

**EDIT** (my own answer): The accepted answer offers to use the `saved_model` API. However, I think it is worthwhile to understand the concept of graph and frozen graph. This [gist link](https://gist.github.com/tokestermw/795cc1fd6d0c9069b20204cbd133e36b) illustrates the main steps that are probably replicated in the `saved_model` api. Basically, you have to:

1. rebuild the graph with redefined input ops;
2. freeze this version;
3. provide the new input to the `input_map` argument when calling `tf.import_graph_def` to reload the model backs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Yes, see this doc https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/saved_model/README.md. In particular, the APIs.Loader.Python section.
2. What do you mean by "compile an estimator"? All the data used by estimator is saved into SavedModel. The reset is simply high-level orchestrating logic. Actual operations like matrix multiplications are provided by the C++ library and run on whatever hardware you have - CPU, GPU, or TPU. XLA is a pretty low-level compiler, far from the Estimator API. For more info about it search for a talk about it "XLA: TensorFlow, Compiled! (TensorFlow Dev Summit 2017)"
3. The link above provides a very high-level API. For the lower layer, see https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/meta_graph. At even lower layer, there is GraphDef (see links in the meta_graph page)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. Do you think you have a link on how to use the saved_model objects? I have some struggle to understand the `input_signatures` and `output_signatures`. In the meantime, I found that the meta graph solution was a good one as you could redefine the input parameters (because you usually train with queues and infer with variables/tensors), freeze the graph and save the graph. I tried the XLA possibility, but my build failed to run launch any session object with it unfortunately.

Comment: @Neo2551 I am not sure what you mean by `input_signatures` and `output_signatures`. If you mean SIgnatureDefs that are stored in SavedModel, you can see this doc https://github.com/tensorflow/serving/blob/master/tensorflow_serving/g3doc/signature_defs.md

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! This documentation is really helpful! I am still struggling to fully grasp the whole concept, but this definitively support me!